# Biding a css element to mediaelement

Tags: jquery, css, coffeescript, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

Hello Im using Media Element and Im trying to bind a display block and none to media element play and pause event.  Any thoughts on how to do this ?

Here is my code

```
$('#mejs-player').mediaelementplayer
  features: [
    "playpause"
  ]
  alwaysShowControls: true
  iPadUseNativeControls: true
  iPhoneUseNativeControls: true
  AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  pauseOtherPlayers: true
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `display block and none to media element play and pause event` ... I guess you meant `selector` instead of `event`

Answer (score 0):

The (css) selector/element you are looking for is

```
.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play button {}
```

On the other hand, you have to separate each API option with a comma like

```
$('#mejs-player').mediaelementplayer({
    // API options
    features: ["playpause"],
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true,
    pauseOtherPlayers: true
});
```

... otherwise you'll get a js error and MEJS won't work.

**Notice** that if you set the option

```
features: ["playpause"]
```

... only the `playpause` button will appear on the *control bar*. If you set it to `none` like

```
.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play button {
    display: none;
}
```

... the control bar will be empty.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aKtEB/)**